# Dimension of quotient of compact totally disconnected group action

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, group-actions, hausdorff-dimension

Assume that $X$ is a compact metric space and $G$ is compact
  totally disconnected group. And $X$ has isometric free $G$-action
  i.e. $gx=x\Rightarrow g=e$.

> Then the following holds $${\rm dim}\ X/G={\rm dim}\ X-{\rm
>   dim}\ G\cdot o$$ where $o\in X$ and dimension is Hausdorff dimension ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume $X/G$ is equipped with the Hausdorff metric between the orbits. What metric on $G$ are you using? You can define a metric on $G$ by restricting  the metric on $Gx$ and then minimizing over all $G$-orbits. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes. That is what I intend. And I think that every orbits will have same Hausdorff dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may happen that
$$\dim_H X/G<\dim_H X-\dim_H (G\cdot o);$$
the following example is almost identical to Example 7.8 in "Fractal geometry" by Kenneth Falconer which provides  spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that
$$\dim_H (X\times Y)>\dim_HX+\dim_HY.$$

Denote by $W(\varepsilon)$ the two-point space with distance $\varepsilon$ between the pair of points.
Consider the $\ell_\infty$-product 
$$X=\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}W(\tfrac1{2^n}).$$
Fix a subset $\Sigma\in  \mathbb{N}$ and consider the natural action of group
$$G=\prod_{n\in\Sigma}\mathbb{Z}_2$$
on $X$.

The orbit can be identified with the infinite product
$$G\cdot o=\prod_{n\in\Sigma}W(\tfrac1{2^n}).$$
and the quotient space can be identified with the infinite product
$$X/G=\prod_{n\notin\Sigma}W(\tfrac1{2^n}).$$

Note that for appropriate choice of $\Sigma$, we have
$$\dim (G\cdot o)= \dim X/G=0$$ 
while
$$\dim  X=1.$$